# Condensing Gremlin queries into one

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop

I have two queries that delete certain vertices in a graph for the same initial vertex

```
g.V(id).outV().drop().iterate()
g.V(id).drop().iterate()
```

Is it possible to combine these two queries into one?

Second question is how can perform some terminal operation on vertices before they are dropped, I tried with sideEffect, but it needs to return value

```
g.V(id).outV().sideEffect(outV().forEachRemainig(x -> // do something)).drop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your initial question you can accomplish this via a `sideEffect()` like this:

```
g.V(id).sideEffect(out().drop()).drop()
```

For the second traversal you can accomplish this by switching the `sideEffect()` to performing the drop and then put the remaining operations to be part of the main traversal stream.  Since `sideEffect()` streams the incoming traversals to the output you will be able to perform operations on them like this:

```
g.V(id).sideEffect(drop()).valueMap()
```

Just a note here, in your original traversals you went `g.V(id).outV()` which is not allowed as `outV()` only works from an edge, so I changed it to `out()` which takes you to the adjacent vertex.